# Object3D define as Light in gltf isn't working as supposed [THREE.JS]

Tags: javascript, three.js, light, gltf

As Seen in the title, I Load my Gltf file with `THREE.GLTFLOADER` everything working great but! When I get to parse every component (mesh, scene, Object3D) I fell on an Object3D as below call `Default_light`. with my genius brain, I try to camera.add(this **gorgeous* baby).

```
Object3D = 
castShadow: false
children: []
frustumCulled: true
isLight: true
layers: Layers {mask: 1}
matrix: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
matrixAutoUpdate: true
matrixWorld: Matrix4 {elements: Array(16)}
matrixWorldNeedsUpdate: false
name: "Default_light"
parent: PerspectiveCamera {uuid: "D0FBA95C-6EE5-4327-AB04-812EDFFCA866", name: "camera", type: "PerspectiveCamera", parent: Scene, children: Array(2), …}
position: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
quaternion: Quaternion {_x: 0, _y: 0, _z: 0, _w: 1, onChangeCallback: ƒ}
receiveShadow: false
renderOrder: 0
rotation: Euler {_x: -0, _y: 0, _z: -0, _order: "XYZ", onChangeCallback: ƒ}
scale: Vector3 {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
type: "Object3D"
up: Vector3 {x: 0, y: 1, z: 0}
userData: {}
uuid: "2B5625C5-A4AA-4E50-B3BC-05EFB15A5AE6"
visible: true
```

**** **AND ... nothing happened.** *****

Yeah feel stupid, but is it because of the KHR_lights? Or something dumber?

If you can help me with this I'll be grateful.

Thank YOU!

Comment: Could you share the glTF model? You may have to enable lights in the exporter options. Or sometimes the light will be a child of another object with light in its name, exporters might have to do that to orient the light correctly.

Comment: I can't show the model (work privacy).
But I think the problem is, like you said, from the exporter option.
Thanks for your help (and your time).